# VS Code error: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager: Attempted to update project that is not loaded

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code, msbuild, omnisharp

I am on windows 10.

here is the end of my omnisharp log:

```
[fail]: OmniSharp.MSBuild.ProjectManager
        Attempted to update project that is not loaded: c:\Users\Asus\learn\Assembly-CSharp.csproj
```

I've tried some fixes, including omnisharp use global mono always and "omnisharp":"latest"  in settings.json.